# Windows 7 hanging network

Tags: windows-7

Their is problem in windows 7 network.
I have recently seen 5-6 computers network stopped working; they all had windows 7 installed in it.
The only solution for me was to restart the computer. After that computer network works fine. I even logged off but logoff is not solving the problem. Only when I restart the computer then the network works properly.

Why is this happening ? And how to rectify this problem.

Comment: There are insufficient details to give you a answer. What have you tried, what have you looked in to.

Comment: Not more than this I can give you the details. Tell me what more details should I mention!!!